# Creating a static page for GitHub project

Tags: github-pages

I know that we can add the readme files or static files for each github project like https://nkgokul.github.io/steem-tutorials

But I would like to have something at https://nkgokul.github.io/ as well so that I can give a summary of my Github pages to the viewers.

Has anybody been able to get this working?

Answer (score 1):

To publish a GitHub page under the root domain of your `github.io` username, you should set up a repository named `username.github.io`, and it will take care of it.

Besides that, any other repository you create and set to publish pages, will be available at `username.github.io/repo-name`.

An example of such repo: [square/square.github.io](https://github.com/square/square.github.io).

If you want to have your repo (also?) under `steem-tutorials` you can mirror that repo to `username.github.io`. It will be both clearer from the name of the repo what it is, and will be easier to change your main site later, since it's not your actual repo.

---

<sup>• Read more at [Getting Started with GitHub Pages](https://guides.github.com/features/pages/)</sup>